# Why are those commands unavailable in ProxyCommand?

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to understand how `ProxyCommand` works,

```
%> ssh -oProxyCommand='ls' root@ubuntu
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

%> ssh -oProxyCommand='useradd' root@ubuntu
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: useradd: not found
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I also tried builtin commands like `env`, but it also has no output.

Any ideas, why can't I execute arbitrary command?

**EDIT**

I know I can execute command like `ssh host $command`, I'm just trying to figure out why ProxyCommand can't just run any command, don't really know why people down vote it.

Answer (score 3):

The `ProxyCommand` option is not an arbitrary command to run on a remote system, but a command for *proxying* some stream of data.  From the [manual page for `ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) (emphasis added):

> **ProxyCommand**
>
> Specifies the command to use **to connect to the server**.  The command string
>     extends to the end of the line, and is executed using the user's shell
>     ‘exec’ directive to avoid a lingering shell process.
>
> In the command string, any occurrence of ‘%h’ will be substituted by the
>     host name to connect, ‘%p’ by the port, and ‘%r’ by the remote user name.
>     The command can be basically anything, and should read from its standard
>     input and write to its standard output.  **It should eventually connect an
>     sshd(8) server running on some machine, or execute sshd -i somewhere**.

If you simply want to run a command on a remote system, provide it at the end of the `ssh` command line, as

```
ssh root@ubuntu ls
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ProxyCommand` you specify is *not* executed on the remote host. It is run on the local (client) side as an alternative connection method to opening a TCP connection (typically port 22) to the remote host. The executable run by `ProxyCommand` is expected to communicate with the local ssh client through `stdout` and `stdin` as a proxy to the socket's own `recv()` and `send()`, but otherwise should behave from the client's perspective as a byte for byte replacement of a TCP session to an actual ssh server.

Typically the usage of `ProxyCommand` is to setup a ssh tunnel through one server to connect to a secondary server that otherwise would not be able to establish a direct connection. Using the ssh client with a `netcat` (nc) command can accomplish this, where `netcat` handles the linking of `stdout` to `send()` on the socket side, and `stdin` to `recv()`.

When you invoke a `ProxyCommand` that does not establish `stdout` and `stdin` to match what the SSH protocol expects in order to negotiate a proper SSH transport, the client bails out with the error: `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`.

If what you actually intend is for the command to be executed on the remote host after the ssh session is established and authenticated, you can include it at the end of the ssh command line (without `ProxyCommand`) and the ssh client will invoke that command on the remote host, instead of an interactive shell.

Try `ssh root@ubuntu ls` instead.